# usage pointer with new in classes and objects

Tags: c++

i want to know what is this pointer pointing to in line 
Bird *object=new Cat;
is it pointing to an object of Bird's type or of Cat's type ?

```
class Bird
{
public:
  Bird() { cout << "Bird's constructor\n"; }
  void fly() { cout << "Bird's Fly\n"; }
  void print() { cout << "Bird's print\n"; }
  ~Bird() { cout << "Bird's destructor\n"; }
};

class Cat : public Bird
{
public:
  Cat() { cout << "Cat's constructor\n"; }
  void fly() { cout << "cat's Fly\n"; }
  void printCat() { cout << "Cat's print\n"; }
  ~Cat() { cout << "Cat's destructor\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  Bird* object = new Cat;
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: It's pointing to `Bird` base class subobject within `Cat` object.

Comment: It is a [flying cat](http://therealweeklyshow.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/flying-cat1.jpg)

Comment: Bird *object=new Cat; quite possibly the worst example code ever!

Comment: What is the output when you run the program?

Comment: @igor Tandetink what is your mean by subobject ?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat then chose a proper example to understand me :)

Comment: @Thomas Matthews the program build the constructor of the base class then the constructor of the derived class(Cat) and functions of the base class (Bird) not the functions related to the other class

Comment: By "subobject", I mean the same thing the C++ language spec does: **1.8/2** Objects can contain other objects, called *subobjects*. A subobject can be a *member subobject* (9.2), a *base class subobject* (Clause 10), or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object is called a *complete object*.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik so that i couldn't access a member of the cat class because of that subobject which is to access only Bird's members? 
and why is he called the constructor of class cat ?

Comment: The expression `new Cat` creates an object of type `Cat`; in the process of creating said object, `Bird` and `Cat` constructors run. The value of `new Cat` expression is a `Cat*` pointer to the newly created object. This pointer undergoes derived-to-base pointer conversion; the resulting `Bird*` pointer is used to initialize `object` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If there are virtual functions, following can be used to determine the object type

Cat *ptr=
dynamic_cast< Cat * > Object;

If (*ptr == NULL)
   cout<< " object is pointing to Bird";

Comment: `dynamic_cast` with no **virtual** members isn't going to be very helpful. There is no polymorphism in this example. And even if there was, *neither* line in this answer has any chance of compiling, said-inaccuracy amplified by absolutely no description of what you're doing nor why you're doing it.

Comment: The <  > brackets and * got trimmed by the stack overflow, edited it with a space, which makes it display the code, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Omar Khaled,

The best way to answer your question is by simply running your code!

As Igor has mentioned, the variable `object` is pointing to  is a Bird base with a class subobject within Cat. This means that the at runtime, the constructor of the base class (the Bird Class) is invoked first, after which the constructor of the Cat class is invoked. The object will go on to inheret the functions overloaded by the derived class, but it will not contain the added functions of your derived class. If you run the following code:

```
int main()
 {
   Bird* object = new Cat;
   object->fly();

   return (0);
 }
```

You will see the following output:

```
 Bird's constructor
 Cat's constructor
 Bird's Fly
```

However, if you run the following code:

```
int main()
 {
   Bird* object = new Cat;
   object->fly();
   object->printCat();
   return (0);
 }
```

You will notice the following error:

```
        main.cpp:27:11: error: class Bird has no member named printCat
       object->printCat();
       ^
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: first thanks bro for this simply answer 
and my understand to it is < Object points to Bird Base and that the reason of inherting functions of Bird class and preventing us from accessing functions of Cat class.and the reason of calling Cat's constructor that subobject of cat's class isn't it ?

Comment: Hey Omar, sorry for the late response- had to step out for a minute; exactly! you got it & said it perfectly!! :0)

Comment: @Devrash Desai , No problem bro :) ,and thx again for ur amazing answer :)